# xsel output contains trash at the end if a long input is piped into it to set the clipboard

Tags: 14.04, clipboard, xsel

To reproduce:

```
seq 10000 | /usr/bin/xsel -b
/usr/bin/xsel -b
```

Observed output: either of:

- nothing
- the correct output
- the correct output + a few lines of trash at the end

The output changes randomly between those three even if I run `xsel -b` multiple times without resetting it with the pipe to stdin!

The input has to be large enough: `seq 1000` does not work. The actual bytes don't seem to matter, only the input size.

Once I do `seq 10000 | /usr/bin/xsel -b`:

- `xclip -selection clipboard -o` is also corrupted, but in a different weird way
- pasting with Ctrl + V on a textarea seems to work normally

I do not reproduce this if I try to set the textarea with:

- Ctrl + C
- `seq 10000 | xclip -selection clipboard`

so it seems to be a problem in the way xsel handles the stdin input.

Using `-i` and `-o` did not change anything.

The problem started today "by itself".

If you reproduce, please add a comment below.

Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64, xsel 1.2.0.

Comment: On current source master, a 4k limit is imposed on xsel output, but the actual clipboard seems to work fine: https://github.com/kfish/xsel/issues/13